# SSRS custom size Dashed line

Tags: reporting-services, line, bar-chart

I'm trouble with a strip line, I need to make it dashed as in the screen below:
[auspicated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q36Q.jpg)

But with the following settings

Under apparence:
`BordeStyle= dashed`

The result is confused because there are too many dashes that is seem continue line:

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc9Pe.jpg)

How can I set the properties to make it as in the first screen?

Comment: Is this dashed line another series or set of values in your chart?

Comment: Can you provide a dataset that could be used to test this out?

Comment: of course, you can use these data: 
CATEGORY    VAL    REF
'b64'                   91       95
'b64'                   91       88

`INSERT INTO [sample]
           ([Category]
           ,[Ref]
           ,[Val])
     VALUES
           ('b64', 95, 91)
INSERT INTO [sample]
           ([Category]
           ,[Ref]
           ,[Val])
     VALUES
           ('b64', 88, 91)`
The aggregation function is Avg,

But I think a simple 2 column bar chart with percent values should be ok to reproduce the report.
 
thanks Thomas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip lines are really designed for adding shaded bands across the chart, not for adding a single thin line. The easiest way to get what you want is to add new new series.

Click the chart and in the pop-up dialogue click the `+` next to values. Choose `expression` and set the value whatever you want, so in your case it will be `=91` or whatever value you need.

Then just format the series by setting the fill color then the border color and the appropriate width in the series properties. You can also choose to not show the series in your legend.

Comment: Using a Serie instead of strip line cause the line start from the top position of the first column and end in the top of the second one, it doesn't go from part to part.